# Como configurar formatos de data no Django 1.7 para todo o sistema

Tags: python, django, data

Há alguma maneira de mudar as configurações de exibição e/ou formatação de data a nível de sistema?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primeiramente para que a configuração de hora/data seja feita manualmente, entre no arquivo `settings.py` e mude o valor de `USE_L10N` para `False`, caso contrário o Django lerá de seus arquivos padrão e configurará a data de acordo com eles.

A variável `DATE_FORMAT`é uma *string* que armazena o formato que a data será exibida no seu sistema. Para o Brasil, utilizamos normalmente o valor 'd/m/Y' (08/02/2015), sendo assim, no `settings.py` essa variável será declarada como segue abaixo:

```
DATE_FORMAT = 'd/m/Y'
```

A outra variável que você deve alterar para que o Django formate sua data corretamente em *inputs* (formulários) é `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` que é do tipo *tuple*.  Os valores dessa *tuple* são lidos na ordem de atribuição, o que significa que se o primeiro formato do *input* não combinar com o primeiro valor, ele tenta combinar com o segundo e assim por diante. Utilizaremos, nesse caso, o mesmo formato da variável acima, mas com uma diferença:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = (
    '%d/%m/%Y',
)
```

Dessa vez, o valor *string* que colocamos nessa *tuple* segue o formato que o Python utiliza para formatar datas, para que assim o Django as formate automaticamente sem nossa intervenção.

Agora você pode utilizar essas configurações para tornar a exibição e formatação de datas comum a todo o seu sistema.